# Build error: base specifier must name a class

Tags: c++, macos, build, makefile, cmake

I am trying to build a big project in Mac OS X with `cmake` and ran into following error which  i am unable to solve.

```
Archive.hpp:92:30: error: base specifier must name a class
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };
```

Code:

```
template<typename T>
class has_save_func
{
    struct Fallback { int save; }; // add member name "X"
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };
    ...
```

Furthermore i have following:

```
Archive.hpp:137:13: error: type 'unsigned long' cannot be used prior to '::'
```

Code:

```
template <class A>
static bool save(const A& data, class OutputArchive& oarchive, const std::string& id, typename boost::enable_if_c<has_save_func<A>::value, A>::type* def=NULL){
    // todo check if A actually is friend with Access class, else return false
    A::save(data, oarchive); // ! Error on this line !
    return true;
}

template <class A>
static bool save(const A& data, class OutputArchive& oarchive, const std::string& id, typename boost::disable_if_c<has_save_func<A>::value, A>::type* def=NULL){
    // todo check if A actually is friend with Access class, else return false
    return serialization::save<A>( data, oarchive, id);
}
```

Code calling (OutputArchive.hpp):

```
template<class T>
void write(const T& data, const std::string& id){
    // the data method must have an implementation of load/save and if not then we try the generic write
    // method which could provide a solution by the implementation itself
    writeEnterScope(id);
    try {
        Archive::Access::save<T>(data, *this, id);
    } catch (...){
        // we fall back to this call
        boost::any adata(data);
        write(adata, id);
    }
    writeLeaveScope(id);
}
```

Code serializeutil.cpp

```
void save(const rw::math::Q& tmp, OutputArchive& oar, const std::string& id){
    oar.write(tmp.size(), "size");
    for(int i=0;i<tmp.size();i++){
        oar.write(tmp[i],"q");
    }
}
```

Could it be a problem with the compiler im using?

Comment: Is `Derived` a class template?

Comment: @juanchopanza, i accidently inserted wrong snippet of code. This is corrected!

Comment: It looks like your template parameter `T` is resolving to an integral type. How are you calling the static function `save`?

Comment: Can't you just use [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/)? Using existing solutions will save you a lot of debugging and boost is carefully designed to have low overhead, so you don't have to fear that.

Comment: @JanHudec, im quite uncomfortable trying to modify too much code as the project is quite huge. But im willing to try if i get some directions.

Comment: @JavaCake: It depends on how much code is already complete and how much of it is actually working. If most of it is working, it's probably easier to fix it. But if it's broken, replacing it with working solution might just be easier option. Look at the library, the code that does not work and than you have to judge whether it would be easier to fix the code or replace it. Even if you decide to fix it, you can learn some techniques you will need for it by reading the library.

Comment: For some reason the code is able to compile under Linux, but in Darwin its failing. Is `size_t` acting different in the two different OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that i may be responsible for the mentioned pieces of code. Something is missing though, and multiple persons already noticed this. The overloaded write functions on the OutputArchive which currently looks something like this:

```
virtual void writeEnterScope(const std::string& id) = 0;
virtual void writeLeaveScope(const std::string& id) = 0;
virtual void writeEnterArray(const std::string& id) = 0;
virtual void writeLeaveArray(const std::string& id) = 0;

// writing primitives to archive
virtual void write(bool val, const std::string& id) = 0;

virtual void write(int val, const std::string& id) = 0;
virtual void write(unsigned int val, const std::string& id){ write((int)val,id); }

virtual void write(boost::uint64_t val, const std::string& id) = 0;
virtual void write(double val, const std::string& id) = 0;
virtual void write(const std::string&  val, const std::string& id) = 0;
```

The serialization part of the software was not supposed to be used yet, but it ended up in the build system anyways. If you comment out the serialize directory in CMakeLists.txt in src/rwlibs then it should work. Or add a write function for an unsigned long:

```
virtual void write(unsigned long val, const std::string& id){};
```

And yes, i did look into Boost.Serialization before venturing into creating yet another serialization framework. I was however trying to create something that would be less intrusive, less templated and more user friendly.... Guess i failed at that...

Comment: I received the correction from Dirk, which i will try later. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

Both errors point to the same: you are trying to use your templates with a non-class, most probably `unsigned int`. In the first case, you would be trying to have `Derived` inherit from `unsigned int`, which is illegal; in the second, you would be trying to call a static method (`save()`) on `unsigned int`, which is illegal again. Looking at the code calling the templates would clarify the issue.

UPDATE: From the information added to the question we can now conclude that this was indeed the case. `tmp.size()`, is most probably an `unsigned int`, so you are calling `oar.write()` with an `unsigned int`; this, in turn, calls `save()` with an `unsigned int`, so it tries to call `unsigned int::save()`, which is illegal, and instantiate class `has_save_func<unsigned int>`, which tries to define `struct Derived : unsigned int, Fallback` which is illegal again.

I'm afraid you will need to redesign your classes if you want them to work with built-in types, such as `unsigned int`. You might do a complete redesign or just overload functions `write()` or `save()`, depending on what you have available.

Comment: Now we need the code that calls `write()`. We still don't know what is `T` there.

Comment: @JavaCake: You only included immediately calling code, which is still template. The error originates further up the stack. You are calling `write` with `unsigned int` reference as first argument somewhere. However that usage is probably supposed to work, so we should focus on how to fix the templates to work with non-class types.

Comment: I have added an additional piece of code which calls `write()` in `OutputArchive`.

Comment: Im not an hardcore C++ person, and this library is very complex for me, but i sense that its only matter of making small changes before it will work. What bothers me is that it can compile in Ubuntu, so i wonder if there is a big difference between the Darwin GCC compiler compared to the Linux one?

Comment: @JavaCake There is no way that the code you have presented can compile in any C++ compiler. Unless there is some additional code (such as function overloads) that we can't see here.

Answer (score 1):

First, it would be better to use existing solution like [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/). It's already debugged and works in all the cases you may need.

However, you should still know where your current code has problems and how to do template machinery like this. So:

> ```
> oar.write(tmp.size(), "size");
>           ^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

This is `unsigned int`. And you do need to serialize it. So you need a write, that can accept primitive types. There are two options:

1. Write non-template overloads for primitive types. Non-template overloads have priority over template ones, so if you write explicit non-template overload with `unsigned int` first argument, the template won't be instantiated and there won't be any error. You will however need overloads for each possible primitive type separately, because template that matches exactly will be still preferred over non-template overload that requires conversion.
2. Use free save function instead of method. Advantage of method is that it can be virtual, but you don't usually need that with template. Advantages of free function are that they can be defined for non-class types and that they can be defined for already existing classes, both of which you often do need in templates. So you would change all instances of the `save` method to free function, drop the `has_save_func` altogether and overload the `save` function for primitive types you need.
3. Amend the `has_save_func` with check whether the template argument is a class type. Non-class types don't have methods, so that's what the other variant will do. You can either use the [boost::is_class](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_class.html) or implement something similar. Boost actually implements it by enumerating all the other options, but it can also be implemented using pointer-to-member, which will cause SFINAE when given non-class type. Unfortunately you don't have anything to cause SFINAE when given class type, so you have to combine with function templates and sizeof and end up with really tricky stuff (I'm sure I've seen it, but really don't remember it).