# Need help troubleshooting Xcode build failures - how can I resolve errors preventing successful builds?

Tags: javascript, react-native

"Encountering errors after reverting changes in specific files (yarn.lock, ios.podfile.lock, ios/project.pbxproj) in a pull request. After reverting, ran 'yarn install' and 'pod install' commands, but received the following error:

sql
Copy code
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SitumSDK":
In Podfile:
ReactNativeSitumPlugin (from `../node_modules/@situm/react-native`) was resolved to 3.4.8, which depends on
SitumSDK (= 3.7.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `SitumSDK (= 3.7.0)`.

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
  Subsequently ran 'pod install --repo-update' but encountered errors in Xcode:

Base specifier must name a class
Expected class name
How can I resolve these errors?

I attempted to address the issues by following suggestions from the following Stack Overflow posts:

1. [Build error: base specifier must name a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686127/build-error-base-specifier-must-name-a-class)
2. [None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: Firebase (~> 6.33.0), Firebase (= 6.33.0, ~> 6.33.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037496/none-of-your-spec-sources-contain-a-spec-satisfying-the-dependencies-firebase)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.